# Phalcon data migrations separated from schema migrations

Tags: php, database, phalcon

Using Phalcon framework and its migrations system, for testing purposes, I need to be able to execute the schema migrations separately from the data migrations.

What I want to do is to have a separate data migrations folder, so on my testing environment I would apply only the schema migrations (for testing purposes, tables should be empty and only populated by fixtures), but on my staging and production environments the data migrations would be applied as soon as the schema migrations are done.

I don't find a way to have two separated sets of migrations in Phalcon. How can I do it?

Comment: A temporary solution that I have adopted, is to use phalcon migrations for the schema migrations, and use [phinx](https://phinx.org/) on another folder for data migrations.